# Make [mavericks] a synonym of [osx-mavericks]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tags [mavericks](/questions/tagged/mavericks) and [osx-mavericks](/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks) both refer to Mac OS X 10.9.

[mavericks](/questions/tagged/mavericks) should be made a synonym of [osx-mavericks](/questions/tagged/osx-mavericks).

Comment: @ColeJohnson itym NBA team.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense. I went ahead and set that up.

We had done the same thing with Lion and Mountain Lion, too.

Comment: Psst, could you also add [tag:osx-10.9] to the Mavericks list?